# text format errors using xlsx package r

Tags: r, xlsx, formats

I am importing an excel file (.xls) with read.xlsx() of the xlsx package in R, but I get the following changes in text formats:

i) three values in the original excel file (entries are in spanish): Alemán ; Portugués ; Búlgaro

ii) the three R data frame values after read.xlsx(): AlemÃ¡n ; PortuguÃ©s ; BÃºlgaro

How can I solve this? I´ve tried to control over colClasses but the only chances are numeric or character. The problem seems to be in the control of accents in the spanish language. I want to get the same values without coding for changes after the import. Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the excel file named (df)i have created as per your variables use XLConnect package
```

[image]

```
library("XLConnect")
> wk=loadWorkbook("df.xls")
> wk=readWorksheet(wk,sheet = "sheet1",startRow = 1)
> wk
  num Alemán. Portugués Búlgaro
1   1 Alemán  Portugués Búlgaro
2   2 Alemán  Portugués Búlgaro
3   3 Alemán  Portugués Búlgaro
4   4 Alemán  Portugués Búlgaro
5   5 Alemán  Portugués Búlgaro
6   6 Alemán  Portugués Búlgaro
7   7 Alemán  Portugués Búlgaro
8   8 Alemán  Portugués Búlgaro
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. With this library, it works. So in practice use the package XLConnect instead of xlsx.

Comment: Basically i use XLConnect package for reading .xls files into R and xlsx package for .xlsx files

Comment: Thanks! I will consider that